# Angular 7 Post file contents as multipart/form-data

Tags: angular, httpclient, multipartform-data

I have the content I want to POST available in a string variable.
I want to use:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
```

... in order to accomplish the same effect as:

```
curl -F "image=@blob.bin" someurl.com
```

... where the contents of my string variable would be what might be in a local file called `blob.bin. I'm not sure how to do it, but this *doesn't* work:

```
this.http.post('http://someurl.com', fileContents)
```

How do you get this effect using Angular 7 and the HttpClient service? I don't have an actual HTML form that I'm interacting with, I just have some prescribed binary / string content that I need to post *as though* it was submitted by a form that looks like (which is the same as what the curl above does):

```
<form method='POST' action='http://someurl.com' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='update'>
  <input type='submit' value='Update'>
</form>
```

I'm sure it can be achieved, just having trouble performing the right incantations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FormData`

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', this.logo, this.logo.name);
this.http.post("upload", formData)
```

In the example, `this.logo` is a `File` object. You can get the file object from your input like so:

```
<input (change)="handleLogoFileInput($event.target.files)" type="file" name="update />
```

and in the component file:

```
handleLogoFileInput(files: FileList) {
  this.logo = files[0];
}
```

Comment: I don't have an <input> I just have a raw string / binary... how do I convert it to a File object to feed to formData.append?

Comment: My bad, I misread. You could use `File​Reader​.read​AsBinary​String()` to read your file. After you acquire the file, the answer above should work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString

Comment: Is your raw string a base64 encoded array of bytes?  Or I’d it a name of a file?

Comment: @Pace it's not even base64 encode, just straight up binary content

Comment: @Sayegh I figured it out...     `const formData: FormData = new FormData(); formData.append('image', new Blob([fileContents], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'file.bin'); `