# interceptor causing "current request is not a multipart request" 500 error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular6, angular8

I'm trying to upload an image to the server but I'm getting that error.

I searched through all the posted questions/answers on **stack overflow** but none solved my problem

**update**
the root of the problem was with `http interceptor` jwt it worked when I commented it.

is there a way to fix it ??

**TS**

```js
onSelectFile(files: File[]) {
    if (files.length > 0) { this.file = files[0]; }    
}

add(){  
     const uploadImageData = new FormData();
     uploadImageData.append('file',this.file);
     uploadImageData.append('user',JSON.stringify(this.user));
     this.service.add(uploadImageData).subscribe(
         data => {this.source=data },       
         error => { console.log("erreur "); }
     );
}
```

**html**

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-lg-3 input-group-sm">
    <label>Preuve d'achat</label><br>
    <input type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event.target.files)" enctype='multipart/form-data'  >
</div>
```

**back**

```java
@PostMapping("/user")
public Object add(
    @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("user")String user) 
    throws JsonParseException, org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7 Post file contents as multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754178/angular-7-post-file-contents-as-multipart-form-data)

Comment: @Eldar nope there is no difference between the answer and my current code !!